# UIButton set touch handler in code

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to accomplish *touching* a `UIButton` and having code run in a *different* class than the owner.

I realize I can do a `touchUpInside` to the button's *owner* (`ClassA`) and then call the method inside `ClassB` that I want called, but is there any way to *expedite* this?

ideas:

- have `ClassB` be the delegate for the `ClassA->UIButton`
- set the `touchUpInside` call in programming to used the function inside `ClassB`

I'm not sure how to *accomplish* either of these ideas :( Input is mas appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One option is to set the button up using

```
[myButton addTarget:yourOtherClass action:@selector(mySelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but this is a bit dangerous because `target` is not retained so you could send the message to a deallocated object.

You could instead set up a protocol

```
MyController.h

@protocol MyControllerDelegate
- (void)myController:(MyController *)controller buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button;
@end

@interface MyController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button;

@end
```

Then in your implementation

```
MyController.m

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myController:buttonTapped:)]) {
      [self.delegate myController:self buttonTapped:button];
    }
}
```

As the method defined in the protocol was not optional I could have instead done a check for `(self.delegate)` to make sure it is set instead of `respondsToSelector`.

Comment: I used the first thing because I'm never dismissing the "target" in the app. However, I very much appreciate you giving the reason against using that because my app will likely change.